# Wireshark dissector - How to use dissectortable:add(pattern, dissector) with ANY pattern?

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am creating a custom dissector for Wireshark. I am adding my dissector to the dissector table kind of like this...

```
udp_table = DissectorTable.get("udp.port")
udp_table:add(7777,my_proto)
```

However, instead of my dissector handling just udp port 7777, I want it to handle ANY udp port or at least a really large range.

How can I do this?

It says in the [documentation](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html), it says I can replace 7777 (the pattern) with a range, but I'm not sure what the syntax is for that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory a range is added using a Lua string for the first argument to `dissectortable:add()`, where the string is a range such as "`7777-8888`".  However, there may be a bug preventing that working right now (see [this ask.wireshark.org thread](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/32810/prefsrange-handling-in-lua)).

Regardless, you should **not** make your dissector operate on *every* UDP port, since it wouldn't be true and would collide with a whole bunch of well-known UDP port uses (e.g., DNS, UPNP, SIP, etc.), as well as dynamically used ones such as for RTP and RTCP.

Perhaps what you really want to do is have a heuristic dissector?  If so, you can make a Lua dissector be a heuristic one starting in wireshark v1.11.3 and beyond (the most recent wireshark version is 1.12rc2).  See the [API docs for proto:register_heuristic](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html#lua_fn_proto_register_heuristic_listname__func_), and the example [dissector.lua script](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=dissector.lua) at the top of the [Lua examples page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples).

Comment: Thanks for including the part about the heuristic dissector. I think that's what I need!